# Custom clipping path over HTML <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, mask

After unsuccessful experimentation with SVG, I'm looking to use another technique to apply a **clip-path** (a custom polygon, like an arrow) to a `<div>`, witch has some other HTML elements inside

```
<div class="firstbox">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

The problematical its about the background outside the `<div>`, it should be visible - no png  over to make a "fake mask". The HTML contents should be visible wihout JS - so no `<canvas>` AFAIK - and able to be indexed by search bots.

Here is it what want to accomplish: http://min.us/mboMRhEQSq

Comment: the question is not completely clear

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It would be nice to see at least an example of the effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Added example. Basically, what I could do with SVG, but AFAIK is very unreliable cross-browser for custom HTML inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research:

1. [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clip-path) is something that Mozilla wants and could help, but only Firefox supports it.
2. [mask](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) CSS property is only supported by Chrome.
3. Coding a SVG with HTML inside, and clipping the content, could make up for the task, but IE9 doesn't render HTML inside foreignObject.
4. Using an SVG to cut only the background image is a solution, but animating inside blocks (to keep them inside the cliping) is a really hard task with [jQuery SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html). [Raphaël JS framework](http://raphaeljs.com) for SVG doesn't support inline SVG.
5. Using a PNG over the content won't do, the background below the `<div>` has to be visible.
6. Using `<canvas>` for the task is a no go, it is not made for rendering html code inside. Also, there are not event handlers like SVG to animate "on hover".

So, the answer is pretty clear: **there is no way to clip(maks) a group of HTML elements**. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a couple of short strings (like in your example) I'd recommend just using plain svg, and use a mask inside the svg. That will work today in all svg-supporting browsers. Or you could wait for all browsers to implement one of the [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11126899/109374) which are not yet standardized (suggestions 1-3).

Here's an [example](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/svg/masking-path-11-b.svg) of using masks in svg. There are some more in the [svg 1.1 testsuite](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/index.html), look for the tests named masking-*.

Comment: After reading you, I decided to do another go with my point 4 and it worked. It was not hard to animate, I just had to select the most nearest parent of the SVG elements, that was something like SVG->switch->g->elements.